# Nested Class needs access to template parameter

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, c++11

I have the following code:

```
template< const int D=1> 
class Parent
{
   class Nested: public OtherClass<D>
   {

   };
};
```

I get the following error when executing the code:

> "unnamed-parameter:" invalid template argument for OtherClass, expected compile-time constant expression.

How can I make this work? I need to have access parameter to the template parameter D, because it's the input for another template.

Comment: the syntax is correct, even `const` is superfluous, it should comile provided that you instantiate `Parent` with a compile-time constant

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: [Works fine](http://ideone.com/p3WLUL) for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers..it was just that my compiler wanted another order regaarding the classes. I defined OtherClass beneath the Nested class. So I changed the order and it worked...